# Return the coefficients of bicubic interpolation

Tags: matlab, interpolation

Suppose, I have a function `z=f(x,y)`. I calculated it in 16 points, say, at the square `[0:3,0:3]` (`x=[0,1,2,3]`  `y=[0,1,2,3]`). Now I want to do bicubic interpolation. But as a result, I need the coefficients of this interpolation.

`interp2` lets me to calculate the result of interpolation in the predefined collocation points, but it doesn't return the coefficients itself.

`spline` works only for 1D functions.

Any idea how I can get the coefficients of bicubic interpolation? 
I need the coefficients, because after that I intend to use them for the numerical solver (and I need the analytical expression of my function for that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wrote down the function that returns coefficients. Assuming 16 values comes from (x=-dx,0,dx,2dx) and (y=-dx,0,dx,2dx). I also wrote function 'Deriv' that takes derivatives of my numerical function with respect to x, y, xy:

```
function [out]=Deriv(in,str,dx)
    switch str
    case 'x'
        out=(circshift(in,[0 -1])-circshift(in,[0 1]))./(2*dx);
    case 'y'    
        out=(circshift(in,[-1 0])-circshift(in,[1 0]))./(2*dx);
    case 'xy'
        out=(circshift(in,[-1 -1])+circshift(in,[1 1])-circshift(in,[-1 1])-circshift(in,[1 -1]))./(4*dx*dx);
    end

function out=bl(in1,in2)
    out=[in1^3, in1^2, in1, 1,in2*[in1^3, in1^2, in1, 1], in2^2*[in1^3, in1^2, in1, 1]...
    in2^3*[in1^3, in1^2, in1, 1]];
end

function out=blx(in1,in2)
    out=[3*in1^2, 2*in1, 1, 0,in2*[3*in1^2, 2*in1, 1, 0], in2^2*[3*in1^2, 2*in1, 1, 0]...
    in2^3*[3*in1^2, 2*in1, 1, 0]];
end

function out=bly(in1,in2)
    out=[0,0,0,0,[in1^3, in1^2, in1, 1], 2*in2*[in1^3, in1^2, in1, 1]...
    3*in2^2*[in1^3, in1^2, in1, 1]];
end


function out=MyBicubic(in,dx)
A=zeros(16,16); C=zeros(16,1);
    A(1,:)=bl(0,0); C(1)=in(2,2);
    A(2,:)=bl(dx,0); C(2)=in(2,3);
    A(3,:)=bl(0,dx); C(3)=in(3,2);
    A(4,:)=bl(dx,dx); C(4)=in(3,3);
    A(5,:)=blx(0,0);  temp=Deriv(in,'x',dx); C(5)=temp(2,2); 
    A(6,:)=blx(dx,0); C(6)=temp(2,3);
    A(7,:)=blx(0,dx); C(7)=temp(3,2);
    A(8,:)=blx(dx,dx); C(8)=temp(3,3);
    A(9,:)=bly(0,0);   temp=Deriv(in,'y',dx); C(9)=temp(2,2);
    A(10,:)=bly(dx,0);  C(10)=temp(2,3);
    A(11,:)=bly(0,dx);  C(11)=temp(3,2);
    A(12,:)=bly(dx,dx); C(12)=temp(3,3);
    A(13,:)=blxy(0,0);   temp=Deriv(in,'xy',dx); C(13)=temp(2,2);
    A(14,:)=blxy(dx,0);  C(14)=temp(2,3);
    A(15,:)=blxy(0,dx);  C(15)=temp(3,2);
    A(16,:)=blxy(dx,dx); C(16)=temp(3,3);
    out=A\C;
end
```